# Convert char to date Then add to last date to get next date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, case

I think the answer is a mix of using CASE expression, CONVERT/CAST, and string manipulation, but I couldn't get the syntax logic to make sense.

I have the following:

| Account | Open Date | Renewal Date | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 2/23/1995 | 5/23/2018 | 12 M |
| 1111 | 2/23/1995 | 5/23/2019 | 12 M |
| 2222 | 6/5/1995 | 4/1/2018 | 7 D |
| 2222 | 6/5/1995 | 4/8/2018 | 7 D |
| 3333 | 7/11/1995 | 7/11/2018 | 24 M |
| 3333 | 7/11/1995 | 3/18/2020 | 24 M |
| 4444 | 8/6/1995 | 12/12/2018 | 91 D |
| 4444 | 8/6/1995 | 1/28/2019 | 91 D |

The objective is to add a flag column that indicates to me that the account was renewed on the correct date.

Duration can be stated in days (D) or months (M).  I want to add the duration to the first renewal date listed. So, for example, Account 1111 was renewed on 5/23/2018 and the duration is 12 M.  So the next renewal date should be 6/23/2019.  If the second renewal date matches the expected, then flag it as correct.  Otherwise, it's wrong.

In the end, I'm looking for something like this:

| Account | Open Date | Renewal Date | Duration | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 2/23/1995 | 5/23/2018 | 12 M |  |
| 1111 | 2/23/1995 | 5/23/2019 | 12 M | RIGHT |
| 2222 | 6/5/1995 | 4/1/2018 | 7 D |  |
| 2222 | 6/5/1995 | 4/8/2018 | 7 D | RIGHT |
| 3333 | 7/11/1995 | 7/11/2018 | 24 M |  |
| 3333 | 7/11/1995 | 3/18/2020 | 24 M | WRONG |
| 4444 | 8/6/1995 | 12/12/2018 | 91 D |  |
| 4444 | 8/6/1995 | 1/28/2019 | 91 D | WRONG |

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Sample data as DDL+DML makes it much easier to assist.

Comment: Given the current schema (where the "Duration" column could be in more than one possible unit, and the column indicates both the unit quantity *and* the unit itself) the solution will require parsing the text of the duration column to determine what the unit is. This is not ideal. It would be better if the unit type was a column of its own, constrained by either a foreign key or a check constraint. In the meantime, however, can you confirm that the format of the text in the duration column is *always* a positive integer, then a space, then a single letter, which is either "D" or "M"?

Comment: Aside... 2018-05-23 plus 12 months = 2019-05-23. What's the logic to get to 2019-06-23 (13 months)?

Comment: @allmhuran Yes, it's always a positive integer, space, then D or M.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Sorry, that was a typo.  Should be 2019-05-23.

Comment: You wrote: "add the duration to the *first* renewal date listed". Your sample data makes this objective ambiguous, because your sample has exactly two rows for the same `{account, Open Date}` pair. What if there were three rows? Do you actually want to add the duration to the "first" row as stated, or to the "previous row in renewal date order"?

Comment: Also, it's not entirely clear which `Duration` value you want to add to the `Renewal Date`, since for every pair of `{account, Open Date}` in your sample data, the `Duration` is the same.
Looking at your sample, what if the first row (top to bottom) had a duration of "1 M", and the second row had a duration of "12 M". If that was the case, then when checking if the second renewal date is correct do you want to add one month, or 12 months?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
With CTE As
(
  Select Account,Open_Date,Renewal_Date,Duration
      ,LAG(Renewal_Date) Over (Partition By Account Order By Account,Renewal_Date) As PreRenDate
      ,SUBSTRING(Duration, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', Duration)) As Interval,
       SUBSTRING(Duration, CHARINDEX(' ', Duration)  + 1, LEN(Duration)) As MD
  From MyData
)
Select Account,Open_Date,Renewal_Date,Duration
      ,Case When PreRenDate IS Null Then '' Else
            Case When MD='M' Then
                Case When DATEADD(Month, CAST(Interval As Int),PreRenDate)=Renewal_Date Then 'Right' Else 'Wrong' End 
            Else
                Case When DATEADD(Day, CAST(Interval As Int),PreRenDate)=Renewal_Date Then 'Right' Else 'Wrong' End 
            End 
       End As Flag From CTE
```

`LAG(Renewal_Date) Over (Partition By Account Order By Account,Renewal_Date)` used to find the previuos `Renewal_Date` value.

`SUBSTRING(Duration, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', Duration))`used to find the interval value from the `Duration` field.

`SUBSTRING(Duration, CHARINDEX(' ', Duration)  + 1, LEN(Duration))` used to find the interval type (month or day) from the `Duration` field.

See a demo from **[*db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=3edfde0d2ead573609203029b4546946)**.